# Behat Firefox crash report

Tags: php, selenium, firefox, behat, geckodriver

How do I get a Firefox crash report for Behat? I saw this https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/CrashReports.html but it was for Python.

This is how I'm starting Selenium.

```
java -jar  -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -log logs/selenium.log > logs/output.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112904/how-to-retrieve-the-crash-data-of-firefox-using-geckodriver-in-java

Comment: You're using selenium grid, and the solution that is mentioned for python (as well as its Java translation mentioned by @Adi Ohana) are for local gecko driver. I guess that you can do the same but use a remote driver instead of the Firefox driver

Comment: Am not familiar with python.